# Converting an (n,m) shaped numpy array into an (n,m,1,1) shaped array

Tags: python, numpy

My starting point is a pandas data frame which I convert into a numpy array:

```
> df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4],"b":[4,5,6,7],"c":[7,8,9,10]})
> arr = df.as_matrix()
```

The array is now 2-dimensional of shape (4,3):

```
> arr
array([[ 1,  4,  7],
       [ 2,  5,  8],
       [ 3,  6,  9],
       [ 4,  7, 10]])
```

What I would like to do is to convert `arr` into its 4-dimensional and (4,3,1,1) shaped equivalent by effectively mapping every singular element like f.x. `5` onto `[[5]]`.

The new `arr` would be:

```
array([[ [[1]],  [[4]],  [[7]]  ],
       [ [[2]],  [[5]],  [[8]]  ],
       [ [[3]],  [[6]],  [[9]]  ],
       [ [[4]],  [[7]],  [[10]] ]])
```

How would I do that elegantly and fast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do `arr[:, :, None, None]` to add two extra axes. Here is an example:

```
In [5]: arr[:, :, None, None].shape
Out[5]: (4, 3, 1, 1)
```

`None` in indexing is a synonym for `np.newaxis`, which selects data and adds a new axis. Many people would prefer to write the above as

`arr[:, :, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]`

for legibility reasons